# Update the route line when user change current location

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I created a map that show routes and directions from current location to the destination, I want to achieve following:

1. I want to always change beginning of **polyline** on the **current location**,
2. I want to always recalculate if user **lost** their first path.

This is my code:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
typealias UIViewType = MKMapView

@Binding var directions: [String]

func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
    return MapViewCoordinator()
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.58393, longitude: 19.52201), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = context.coordinator
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    // Prijepolje
    let p2 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.000000, longitude: -75.000000))
    
    let request = MKDirections.Request()
    
    request.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: p2)
    request.transportType = .automobile
    
    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    
    directions.calculate { response, error in
        guard let route = response?.routes.first else {
            return
        }
        mapView.addAnnotations([p2])
        mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20), animated: true)
        self.directions = route.steps.map { $0.instructions }.filter {
            !$0.isEmpty
        }
    }
    
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    
}

class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer  = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        
        renderer.strokeColor = .blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 5
        return renderer
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            // Do something with the updated location if needed
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: This is my current behaviour]

This is my current behaviour, the directions and route are only created when MapView is called, and never updated again.

I'm using Xcode 14.2, and iPhone 11.